# Facebook sharing content problem

Tags: facebook, open-graph

I have problem when sharing posts (only posts) on Facebook, which is that there is no image or title or any thing but the blog link, while at the same time, I can share pages without any problem. I don't know why this is happening, because  the same setting is used for both posts and pages.

If you check the source  code you will see the open graph required data.

**Please test those links**

Post link : https://prosentra.com/wordpress-loop/

Page link : https://prosentra.com/php-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Thank god, the problem is solved, i had some problems when checked the post page with [w3.org Validator](https://validator.w3.org), i have worked on solving these issues and the problem is solved.